# Local pgAdmin connecting to Digitalocean postgres droplet

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, putty

I have a Digitalocean droplet that has postgres installed. Its running an can connect to it from the digitalocean console but im trying to connect from my local dev machine at home and i cant seem to make this work. Digitalocean droplet has SSH installed and i can successfully SSH into it from putty at home.

At home i am locally running postgres 10 for development testing, so this is the pgAdmin that i am using to try to connect to the digitalocean instance of postgres.

I am trying to figure out how to use putty to tunnel into the digitalocean SSH connection and use digital oceans 5432 port for connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finally found something that worked. In the Putty SSH tunnel section i added a Local tunnel with source port: 8000 and the destination: 127.0.0.1:5432

Once i save that and connect, NOW i can us my local pgAdmin to connect to the digitalocean droplet postgres connection